# Book recommendations for self-study at the level of 3rd-4th year undergraduate

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, complex-analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations

I have only recently discovered an interested in mathematics and I could only take a year off work to be back at school. Needless to say, for financial reasons (couple of mortgages) I will need to return to work soon. Luckily though, I will be setting up a nice office with whiteboard etc to do some serious thinking in!

I have found some examples as well as a lot of resources for first and second year courses, though by time I return to work basically any 2nd year math class that my university offers as well as most of the third year ones I will have taken.

I know there are a ton of math professors on here, so I'm wondering if anyone can recommend a good textbook for learning.

- PDE (never done, save for some physics related stuff)
- Topology (never done but I am extremely interested in this topic)
- Complex Calculus (complex being imaginary numbers)
- Abstract Algebra (done second year only)
- Chaos (done intro only)
- Advanced ODE

As well as any other texts/books you find interesting (Graph theory etc) most things involving logic I find very intriguing basically anything but statistics.

I will have also completed a third year level analysis course so hopefully I can get through the math language. That being said, as dummy-proof of a layout as possible is preferred. Anyone out there that happens to have some material lying around to a related course that wouldn't mind emailing it to me or leaving there website below so I could steal some assignments and solutions I would really appreciate that as well. Most stuff I find on the internet isn't at the 3rd/4th year undergraduate level.

Comment: Complex Numbers A to Z is a great book .

Comment: Look at the lecture notes and excercises at [OCW](http://ocw.mit.edu), check out [Coursera](http://www.coursera.org). William Chen's [lecture notes](http://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/~maths/notes/wchen/ln.html) for first/second year are nice.

Comment: http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/wtrench/texts/TRENCH_REAL_ANALYSIS.PDF Real Analysis Textbook

Comment: http://www.math.psu.edu/katok_a/TOPOLOGY/
its not the one linked below but its a free res has some hw prblms as well by author Topology txtbook

Comment: What book did you use for your analysis course?

Comment: http://biblioteca.matem.unam.mx/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=7156:free-textbook-introduction-to-real-analysis-by-william-f-trench&catid=1:latest-news&Itemid=45

Comment: The link to it above this one Intro to real analysis by William F trench. There are some old copies in print but the latest revision is free in that link from the prof. Thats the text i used in my third year analysis course, if you have a good handle on calculus this text is quite good. if you haven't done any 3rd year calc i would recommend something at a  lower level then this text however.

Answer (score 1):

1, PDE : PDE by Fritz John

1. Topology : Basic topology by Armstrong
2. Complex Calculus : Complex analysis by T W Gmaelin
3. Abstract Algebra : Topics in algebra by herstein , Abstract algebra by dummit and foote
4. ODE and Chaos : Differential equations, dynamical systems, and an introduction to chaos     by Hirsch ,   DE with historical notes by simmons